# How do I assign associated products to a grouped product programatically in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, grouped-products, product-linking

I have the following abridged code that I believe *should* assign a product to a grouped product; however when ran it doesn't create the assignment; that is - no entry is saved into the `catalog_product_link` table.

I've tried a few different ways (using the Data APIs/Interfaces) but have so far come up blank.

```
$obj = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');

$product = $obj->create()->load(904); // productId of my grouped product

$product->setProductLinks([
    [
        "sku" => "group_sku",
        "link_type" => "associated",
        "linked_product_sku" => "simple_sku",
        "linked_product_type" => "simple",
        "position" => 1,
        "extension_attributes" => ["qty" => 1]
    ]
]);


$product->save();
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong / or has anyone got a working code example?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem trying to create related, upsell, cross-sell.
I ended using something this:

```
$q = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$q->getConnection('core_write')->query("insert into catalog_product_link (linked_product_id, product_id,link_type_id) values (".$linked_product_id.",".$product_id.",".$link_type_id.")");
```

not the best way, I'm sure, but it works!.

Comment: Only way that it work on grouped products for me....

Answer (score 0):

The data looks right, but you need to create an array of \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\Link objects and then pass that to setProductLinks rather than the data array.

I gave a full code example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40529460/2828129

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me.

```
 $associated = array();
$position = 0;

foreach($childrenIds as $productId) {

    $position++;
    $productRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $linkedProduct = $productRepository->getById($productId);
    $productLink = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface');
    $productLink->setSku($product->getSku())
        ->setLinkType('associated')
        ->setLinkedProductSku($linkedProduct->getSku())
        ->setLinkedProductType($linkedProduct->getTypeId())
        ->setPosition($position)
        ->getExtensionAttributes()
        ->setQty(1);

    $associated[] = $productLink;

}

$product->setProductLinks($associated);
$product->save();
```